# How to get the guide for older api versions. The online Android Guide uses Android 4.1

Tags: android, android-layout

I was looking at an article talking about Layouts [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html) . When I run the code I found multiple errors about not finding some classes. I looked at the button of the page i found it is Android 4.1. Also the layout tutorial only shows linear and relative ( no other layouts , table, frame ? ) I want to get the guide for the older versions and I want also to understand what is happening there.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're browsing the [Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/package-summary.html) you can filter by API version. That will be the most accurate. If you're looking for specific guides for a specific version however, Google is your friend.

Comment: We can also find the documentation of specific API version in the downloaded api folder under docs directory. 
Using the SDK Manager you can download any documentation for any API version.